# How can you change the admin dashboard URL without symlinking?

Tags: wp-admin, urls, dashboard, apache, site-url

I'm interested in changing the WordPress admin dashboard URL without using a third-party plugin.

**NOTE:** I know that 'security by obscurity' is not the best security measure; I plan on using other methods too, but I would like to do this as an extra step.

In essence, I want to rename the `wp-admin` part of URLs to something else, e.g. `XX/secret/YY` instead of `XX/wp-admin/YY`.

Then, if users try accessing `XX/wp-admin/YY`, they receive a `404` not found error. They should only be able to see the admin pages from `XX/secret/YY`.

I have seen multiple resources online for changing the login path, but have not been able to work out how to change how other administration pages are accessed.

`wp-admin` is hard-corded into core files, so I have tried using symlinking so that files from within `wp-admin/` can still be included by WordPress. This is what I have done so far:

1. Added a rewrite rule to `XX/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^secret/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

2. Defined these constants in `XX/wp-config.php`:

```php
define('ADMIN_DIR', 'secret');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
```

3. Used filters for these hooks:

```php
add_filter('site_url', fn ($url) => str_replace('wp-admin', ADMIN_DIR, $url));
add_filter('admin_url', fn() => site_url(ADMIN_DIR));
add_filter('user_admin_url', fn() => site_url(ADMIN_DIR) . '/user');
```

4. Created a symlink from `XX/wp-admin` to `XX/secret` with `ln -s ./wp-admin ./secret`.

This results in both `XX/wp-admin/YY` and `XX/secret/YY` being accessible. However, adding a rewrite rule to return `404` for `XX/wp-admin` does so for both - I am unsure on how to only hide `XX/wp-admin` from users.

I know there may be plugins to achieve this, but I want to learn how to do this myself, either with Apache or WordPress alone.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This might not be possible, `wp-admin` is hardcoded in lots of places. There are redirects and shortcuts such as `/admin` or `/login` but those redirect to `wp-admin` and the login URL rather than rewriting/replacing them

Comment: I usually do not recommend this. What you're trying is "security by obscurity", you add no real benefit, because the real (secret) URL may be leaked from various places and serious attackers can still try it. If you actually want to improve the security, add Basic Auth, 2FA, firewalls, etc. to your wp-admin.

Comment: @kero I know that "security by obscurity" is not the best security measure and I don't plan on using this alone to protect my site. I will look into other methods such as those you've mentioned, but I've been asked to do this renaming as an additional step.